# read data having a column with more than 1 entry

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to read the following data

```
name            nr         rep             meters
Bill            0           1              135
Chill           0           2              81, 81
Billy           5           6              175, 205, 187, 174, 240, 198
Sambouka        5           7              130, 113, 117, 118, 130
Chile           0           1              120
```

I tried the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s+')
```

but obviously it did not work because the last column `meters` has more than 1 entry. Any suggestions?

Note that the data I am dealing with has around 100 rows, so this is not the complete data.

### EDIT

Using @Abbas answer, it works:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
print data['meters'][2] # output: 175, 205, 187, 174, 240, 198
```

but

```
print len(data['meters'][2]) # output 28 !
```

whereas the output should be `6`.

After all, I would like to

```
plt.hist(data['meters'][2])
```

Comment: `data['meters'][2]` appears to now be a string. Try converting it to a list of integers, and you should be able to plot the histogram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also only use any number of spaces that are *not* preceded by a comma as separator using a regex negative lookbehind:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='(?<!,)\s+')
```

If you also want to ignore spaces followed by commas, add a negative lookahead:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='(?<!,)\s+(?!,)')
```

---

After splitting, the combined value is of course a string and not a list. Your example consists of 28 characters, so the output is what you would have to expect.

You can convert this string to a Python list of integers using a list comprehension:

```
my_list_of_ints = [int(n) for n in my_string.split(",")]
```

or using the builtin `map` function:

```
my_list_of_ints = map(int, my_string.split(","))
```

Comment: @aloha After splitting, the combined value is of course a string and not a list. Your example consists of 28 characters, so the output is what you would have to expect. You can convert this string to a Python list of integers using `[int(n) for n in my_string.split(",")]` (list comprehension) or `map(int, my_string.split(","))` (map builtin).

Answer (score 3):

Try this, will consider 2 or more spaces only as a seperator:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s{2,}')
```

**Added the following image for clarification:**
[image]

Comment: It works, yet I get a warning: `test.py:3: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  data = pd.read_csv('data', sep='\s{2,}')`

Comment: Say `data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')` you will not get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

this will get it done

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: It is not working, I get the following error: `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 5`

Comment: I neglected to see that you had spaces in some of your field values.  My apologies.  I'll get something working.